# assemblies not resolving while creating instance from AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, assemblies, appdomain

```
var processAssembly  = Assembly.LoadFile(baseLocationCCDebugFolder+"\\CC.dll");
var processType = processAssembly.GetType("CC.Executor.CCProcess",true,true);

AppDomainSetup appDSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
{
  ApplicationBase = baseLocationCCDebugFolder,
  //PrivateBinPath = processAssembly.CodeBase
};

StrongName fullTrustAssembly = processAssembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();

AppDomain executionDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ExecutionDomain",null,appDSetup,internetPS,fullTrustAssembly);
CCProcess process =(CCProcess)executionDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(processAssembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName, processType.FullName);
```

im encountering an error on the last line of this code which goes like this.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'D:\\work\\compilerCom\\CompileCom_Build_4_newArchitecture\\CompilerCom\\CC\\bin\\Debug\\CC.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)<br/>
```

im still figuring my way in app domain. 
what am i doing wrong?

EDIT:-
the value of `baseLocationCCDebugFolder` variable is `D:\\work\\compilerCom\\CompileCom_Build_4_newArchitecture\\CompilerCom\\CC\\bin\\Debug`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is not the Assembly not being found but one of the referenced assemblies not loading correctly.  You may need to handle the resolve assembly event in the parent appdomain.  There is a good post here describing it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/0a18ed66-6995-4e7c-baab-61c1e528fb82/

Comment: You can also handle `ReflectionTypeLoadException` and look at the `LoaderExceptions` property to determine if any referenced assemblies cannot be resolved. Easier than handling the event IMHO.